# How to get content from a paragraph tag inside div via DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

How can I get paragraph tag inside a specific ID via `DOMDocument()`?

For example, the HTML is this:

```
<div id='content'>
xxx yyyy zzzz


fffuuu uuuueee
xxx yyyy pppppp zzzz

<p>i need only this line</p>
</div>
```

I just want to take `P` tag in content id `DIV`...

**Note 1:** I get whole content of the DIV with:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$newcontent = $xpath->query("//*[@id='content']");
```

**Note 2:** Don’t say `getElementsByTagName`; the HTML contains too many `P` tags.

Comment: Well... why can you then get the content from `p` tag which is inside a `div` tag with the id `content` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dare a `getElementsByTagName` :) - you dont need `xpath` at all :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$p=$doc->getElementById('content')->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
echo $p->nodeValue;
```

outputs

```
i need only this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) expression:

```
$newcontent = $xpath->query("//*[@id='content']/p");
echo $newcontent->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Output:

```
i need only this line
```

If you need the text from multiple paragraph tags, then use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($newcontent as $tag) {
    echo $tag->nodeValue;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/92092)